# get gender and locale using Facebook app-scoped user id

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am trying to get gender and locale using V2.0/V2.1 app-scoped user id, and I can't find it using https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/[APP-SCOPED-ID]

Anyway, I can see it for /me.

Does this requires permissions in V2?

Thank you,
Dan

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem ?

Comment: unfortunately, no. Another way is using some gender API based on first/last name which are still available.